# Getting tough expression in SSIS conditional split

Tags: sql-server, expression, ssis

Anyone know how to achieve this requirement? The start date will always be 73 hours before the end date. While the end date will be the nearest 8am but its definitely a datetime of a past. I want to do it in conditional split using expression.
Scenarios:
Datetime when package run: 24/12/12 0900
Startdate: 21/12/12 0700
Enddate: 24/12/12 0800

Datetime when package run: 25/12/12 2300
Startdate: 22/12/12 0700
Enddate: 25/12/12 0800

Datetime when package run: 26/12/12 0759
Startdate: 22/12/12 0700
Enddate: 25/12/12 0800

Datetime when package run: 26/12/12 0800
Startdate: 22/12/12 0700
Enddate: 25/12/12 0800

Datetime when package run: 26/12/12 0805
Startdate: 23/12/12 0700
Enddate: 26/12/12 0800

As u can see i want the data to be included from my soure to my staging span accross 73hrs. I want 73hrs worth of event data. So EVENT_D + EVENT_T should be between the Startdate and Enddate

What i have tried:

```
    (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(EVENT_D + " " + EVENT_T) >= DATEADD("HH",-73,GETDATE()) && (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(EVENT_D + " " + EVENT_T) <= DATEADD("HH",8,(DT_DBDATE)(GETDATE()))
```

It does not give me what i want. What i have tried only give me 73 hrs ago till now. Not what i wanted. Desperately need guidance. I am using SSIS 2005.
Thanks in Advance,
10e5x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the sort of too-complicated-for-a-simple-expression logic that makes me reach for a Script Task - which, since you're using SSIS 2005, has to be written in VB.NET:

```vb
Public Sub Main()
    Dim runDate As DateTime = CDate(Dts.Variables("RunDate").Value)
    Dim startDate As DateTime
    Dim endDate As DateTime

    ' Set the end date to be 8AM on the run date
    endDate = New DateTime(runDate.Year, runDate.Month, runDate.Day).AddHours(8)
    If runDate <= endDate Then
        ' Use yesterday for the end date
        endDate = endDate.AddDays(-1)
    End If
    startDate = endDate.AddHours(-73)
    Dts.Variables("StartDate").Value = startDate
    Dts.Variables("EndDate").Value = endDate
    Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success
End Sub
```

In case it's not obvious, both `StartDate` and `EndDate` are package variables that you add to the `ReadWriteVariables` collection of the Script Task.

Comment: hi, wonder if u are there. actually my '73' is supposed to use a package variable which value is from db. So can i replace the -73 to @maxHrs? in db maxHrs is in varchar.

Comment: Hi i tried yours but i am very confused for the variable part. I am v new to SSIS. i got this Error: The element cannot be found in a collection. This error happens when you try to retrieve an element from a collection on a container during execution of the package and the element is not there.    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Variables.get_Item(Object index)
   at ScriptTask_1e93d3b55b1647d492d0128648ff5f8a.ScriptMain.Main()

Comment: i managed to solve the error but there something wrong with the logic, still testing

Answer (score 1):

Try the following logic in TSQL:

```
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME, @END_DATE DATETIME, @START_DATE DATETIME;

SET     @DATE = '2012-12-26 08:00:00'

SELECT  @END_DATE = CASE WHEN @DATE > DATEADD(HOUR,8,CAST(CAST(@DATE     AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
                         THEN DATEADD(HOUR,8,CAST(CAST(@DATE     AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
                         ELSE DATEADD(HOUR,8,CAST(CAST(@DATE - 1 AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
                    END;

SELECT  @START_DATE = DATEADD(HOUR,-73, @END_DATE);
SELECT  @START_DATE, @END_DATE;
```

Once you have the border cases handled correctly, translating this into SSIS should be no problem at all.

Comment: i am sorry, i quite new to ssis,actually i already have an tsql solution but i do not know how to implement it in SSIS.I will figure that out and try your solution too

Comment: this works too, Thanks, but i prefer doing it on a script, den having a conditional split to call the variables declared